# Detailed guidance about WCF Security

Tags: wcf, security

Guys, I'm looking for some detailed guidance about WCF Security. I've read [Juval Lowy's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596526997) and [WCF Security Guide](http://wcfsecurityguide.codeplex.com/), but I'm still looking for verbose manual.
I'm especially interested how some WCF security options influence on SOAP messages (cause clients of my services aren't .NET applications).

Could you point to any similar books/blogs/articles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already read two main sources. You can also check official [WCF Service Interoperability site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/ff521748). It contains some white papers which are not related only to security. But if you really want to dive deep into WCF interoperability, learn to use Fiddler, WCF tracing and message logging and study WS-Security specifications.

I also recommend [Yaron Naveh's blog](http://webservices20.blogspot.com/).